Remove Track Package link before order table from WooCommerce Refund emails
I am Working with the WooCommerce Purolator plugin and the following action hook:
    /*
     * Action hook for executing code before the order table in a WooCommerce email.
     *
     * @param WC_Order $order The order object.
     * @param bool     $sent_to_admin Whether the email is sent to the admin or not.
     * @param bool     $plain_text Whether the email is plain text or not.
     * @param WC_Email $email The WooCommerce email instance.
     */
    public function action_woocommerce_email_before_order_table( $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email ) {

        $order_id = $order->get_id();
        $purolator = new WC_Shipping_Purolator();
        $purolatorLabel = new WC_Shipping_Purolator_Ajax();
        $purolatorLabel->process_label( $order_id );

        $shipment_pin = opmc_hpos_get_post_meta( $order_id, '_tracking_number', true );
        $puro = opmc_hpos_get_post_meta( $order_id, '_purolator', true );
        // echo '<p><a href="#">Print Purolator Lable '.$order_id.' '.$shipment_pin.'</a></p>';.
        if ( $shipment_pin ) {

            $label_url = $purolator->get_documents( $shipment_pin );

            if ( ! empty( $label_url ) ) {

                // echo '<p><a href="'.$label_url.'">Print Purolator Label</a></p>';.
                echo '<p><a href="https://www.purolator.com/en/shipping/tracker?pins=' . $shipment_pin . '">Track Purolator Package</a></p>';

            }
        }
    }
}

new WC_Purolator();

This outputs a "Track package" link in all customer order emails. I would like to remove it from the customer_refunded_order email that get sent.
Not a WooCommerce developer but think I'm on the right track
add_action( 'action_woocommerce_email_before_order_table', 'action_email_before_order_table', 2, 4 );
function action_email_before_order_table( $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email ) {
    // Targeting "refund" order email notification sent to customer.
    if ( 'customer_refunded_order' === $email->id ) {
        // Not sure about what should be written below though.        
        remove_action( 'action_woocommerce_email_before_order_table', array( WC()->mailer(), 'order_details' ) );
    }
}

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Please, for the 1st function action_woocommerce_email_before_order_table, you didn't provide in your question, the hook used with add_action() in WC_Purolator class constructor. Could you add it in your question? Nobody can guess things by magic.
